# How come network drives are available in other locations but not on her local machine?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, citrix

We have a user that is able to access her network drives from Citrix and from the VMs.  However, on her local machine either 1 of 2 things will happen. 1) She will see them there and can open them up but cannot actually navigate them.  She gets an error when she tries to open up a drives contents. 2) She sees the drives but they have a red X through them like they were not able to be loaded.

What are some troubleshooting steps I can take for this. I'm kind of stumped by this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try going on the machine where the network shares are actually located like the actual directories/folders themselves and setting the permissions to be more relaxed so she can get in like right click and properties then see permissions there.

Answer (score 0):

Try browsing to the server from her machine (\servername) and see if you can access the shares from there.  It may be a network issue in that her machine is in another subnet that isn't allowed access where as your Citrix server and File Server are both on the same subnet so Citrix can access the shares.